# Number 2 Text - Negative Number bug

Tags: python, python-2.7, negative-number

I was writing a code where I input (for example) 1 and my output is one.

But when I got to negative numbers it all went wrong...

```
numbers = "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine".split()
numbers.extend("ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen
sixteen".split())
numbers.extend("seventeen eighteen nineteen".split())
numbers.extend(tens if ones == "zero" else (tens + "-" + ones) 
    for tens in "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty     ninety".split()
    for ones in numbers[0:10])


 lol = int(raw_input ("Insert a number between 1 to 99! "))

while lol>=100:
 lol = int(raw_input ("Insert a number between 1 to 99! Not above 100!!!!!!! "))

  if lol <= -1:
        print "minus" + " " + numbers[lol]
else:
 print numbers[lol]
```

But when I wrote -7 I got minus ninety three..

Is there a way to fix it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because if you use negative numbers in a list, Python counts backwards.
ex
    `e=[1,2,3,4,5]
    e[-2] is equal to 4`
What you should do is use the math.abs() to make it an absolute value number.

Comment: I just changed the "minus" line to `print "minus" + " " + numbers[0 - lol]`

Comment: @Telep0rter - Couldn't you just use `-lol`? Also, you can shorten it to `"minus "`.

Comment: That's true. I didn't even consider that you could just multiply by -1.